# On_change callback does not provide the control id for number in TAipy

Tags: python, taipy

I want to update a partial dynamically. I want my partial named p to contain one `number` control for each row of a dataframe. So I have multiple controls.

I am trying the following code:

```
def display(state):
    scenario = tp.create_scenario(scenario_cfg)
    df = scenario.scores.read()
    state.p.update_content(state, build_partial(df))

def build_partial(df):
    part = "<|layout|columns=1|\n"
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        part += "<|{" + str(row["chips"]) + " }|number|on_change=add_chips|id=" + str(index) + "|>"
        part += "\n\n"
    part += "|>\n" 

def add_chips(state, var_name, value):
    # HOW TO KNOW WHICH NUMBER CONTROL TRIGGERED THE CALLBACK?
    pass

gui = Gui(pages=pages)
p = gui.add_partial("No content")
```

When the value of a control is updated I would like to execute the function `add_chips`. Since I have multiple controls, I want know which control called the function. But the on_change method does not pass any id.

I tried with `on_change` callback as explained above and with the `on_action` as well without success.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Can you also provide the scenario_cfg to help us understand your use case?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you want, I recommend using tables, which require less configuration from you. Here's a version of the code demonstrating how to create an editable table:

- Create a Pandas DataFrame (*df*) to be displayed and updated.
- Make the table editable. When a value in the table is changed, the *on_edit* function is called.

```py
import pandas as pd
from taipy.gui import Gui

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['chips', 'values'])

def display(state):
    #scenario = tp.create_scenario(scenario_cfg)
    #df = scenario.scores.read()
    #state.df = scenario.scores.read()
    state.df = pd.DataFrame({"chips": ["chip_1", "chip_1"],
                             "values": [1, 2]})

def add_chips(state, var_name, action, payload):
    id = payload["index"]
    col = payload["col"]
    value = payload["value"]

    print(f"Id: {id}, Col: {col}, Value: {value}")
    print("Row\n", state.df.loc[id, :])

    temp = state.df.copy()
    temp.loc[id, col] = value
    state.df = temp

def on_init(state):
    # This function is called at the app start
    display(state)

pages = {"/":"",
         "Page_1":'<|{df}|table|on_edit=add_chips|editable[chips]=False|>'}

gui = Gui(pages=pages)
gui.run()
```

[image]

Regarding your previous code, some explanations and an updated version are provided below. However, I would not recommend using this code as it is more complex than the one suggested above.

The *id* parameter of a visual element corresponds to the CSS id of the visual element to change its appearance and not the id itself in Taipy. You can differentiate variables with their names (*varname*, what is between `{` `}`). However, your variables of `row['chips']` were never initialized so it would raise an error.

The solution would be to use a dictionary to change your different variables.

- Define a *values* dictionary as an empty dict, updated in *display*.
- Create visual elements based on this dictionary in *build_partial*, returning the string at the end to build the partial.

In this code, two visual elements will be created, and when changed, it will call the *add_chip* function with different *varnames*.

```py
import pandas as pd
from taipy.gui import Gui

values = {}

def display(state):
    #scenario = tp.create_scenario(scenario_cfg)
    #df = scenario.scores.read()
    df = pd.DataFrame({"chips": ["chip_1", "chip_2"],
                                "values": [1, 2]})
    state.values = {df['chips'][i]: int(df['values'][i]) for i in range(len(df))}
    state.p.update_content(state, build_partial(state.values))

def build_partial(values_dict):
    part = ""
    for key in values_dict.keys():
        part += "<|{values."+str(key)+"}|number|on_change=add_chips|label="+str(key)+"|>\n\n"
    return part

def add_chips(state, var_name, value):
    print(var_name, value)


def on_init(state):
    # This function is called at the app start
    display(state)

pages = {"/":"",
         "Page_1":'<|part|partial={p}|>'}

gui = Gui(pages=pages)
p = gui.add_partial("No content")
gui.run()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I dont use tables 'cause I display some columns of my df with buttons, and I dont know if buttons work in tables:

        part += "<|layout|columns=1 1 1 1 |\n"
        part += "<center> " + str(row["convention"]) + "</center> \n\n"
        part += "<|+1|button|on_action=add_one_convention|id=" + str(index) + "|>\n\n"
        part += "<|-1|button|on_action=remove_one_convention|active=" + str(row["convention"] > 1) + "|id=" + str(index) + "|>\n\n"
        part += "<|X2|button|on_action=double_conventions|id=" + str(index) + "|>\n\n"
        part += "|>\n\n"

Comment: I needed the context to see the use case better. Do you think my answer is good enough for you, or would you like more help integrating it into your code? Some comments on this code. As said previously, you don't need the 'id' if you don't use CSS. Manipulating a dictionary will allow achieving your goal this way. However, I would push for not using a partial if possible. You can have a selector to choose what you want to change and then apply buttons on the appropriate object, for example.